# dd/23/yy could not be understood as a date and time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The time & date are added correctly with the following calendar time picker:

```
<p:calendar value="#{myBean.time1}" mode="inline"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"/>
```

But when I change pattern to “HH:mm:ss.SSS dd/MM/yyyy” the following error is displayed:

' 04:23:10.599 dd/23/yy' could not be understood as a date and time. Example: 11:59:24.412 15/12/2017

How can I get the time to be displayed before date correctly?

Comment: So dd/11/yy works? (23 not being a real month)

Comment: It doesn't matter what date I pick, day of the month is always displayed as dd and year as yy.

Comment: what primefaces version you are using ?

Comment: I have tried 5.3 and 6.1

Comment: Can you try 6.2-SNAPSHOT (need to build it from the source in GitHub)? There has been a change in the calendar pattern processing if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have never built any sources from GitHub and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Information how to build from source can be found [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Building-From-Source)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Primefaces bug and should be fixed with 6.2. More details here:

- [Github Issue#472](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/472)
- [Google Code Issue#6790](https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/6790)
- <strike>[Fix in 6.2](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/e1d97ca9320084c39375abf0535b7358cf79b083#diff-fbb42977b8aec2865f274569b8dace68)</strike>

**Update:**
I just checked this with the current `6.2.RC2-SNAPSHOT` and this didn't work. I created an [issue on github #3227](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3227)

Comment: I had the same error with versions before 6.2. Now it works fine when updated to version 6.2